# How to import maven project with build project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, visual-studio-code

I am trying to import a Maven project in VS Code. The issue is that it doesn't index the project like IntelliJ.

Also, I have an IntelliJ build project, how can I do that for vscode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does not have built-in Maven support like IntelliJ IDEA does. VS Code is a code editor, while IntelliJ is a fully-featured Java IDE.

However, you can call Maven commands from VS Code in multiple ways.

The first step is to open the folder of your Maven project.

**A) Call Maven from integrated terminal**

VS Code has an [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) which can be used to call Maven commands too. Press `` Ctrl+` `` then you can type your Maven commands, e.g. `mvn test`.

**B) Create tasks for Maven**

In VS Code you can [define tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) and then you can call them from the command palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). You will create a `tasks.json` file for your project and you will be able to call Maven tasks for that project with 1-2 shortcut key press.

Here is [another tutorial](https://gorkem1.gitbooks.io/visual-studio-code-for-java/chapter-1/Maven-Create.html) for using Maven in VS Code.